# how to put values into HashMap<int,List<String>>

Tags: java, hashmap

How to put and get the below values in/from HashMap as Key and values

```
Key Value
1   "a"
1   "b"
1   "C"

2   "x"
2   "y"
2   "z"
```

Comment: You should write a code that instruct the computer to do that.

Comment: You managed to ask a "famous question" according to your bagdes, so why do you aks this comparably stupid one to ruin your points? You should show what you have done so far and where do you have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    map.put(1, list);
```

Comment: It is not helpful to provide code without explanation and support OPs bad approach to his problem.

Comment: he ask how to insert?? then only i'm post code. i think this code is enough for a programmer.

Comment: You didn't get my point: He asked a very basic java question, which he should be able to answer himself if he bothered to have a quick look into the API (as mentioned by @Corjava). So, it its counterproductive to give him complete code, firstly because it's given without any comment and secondly, it should not be supported on SO to answer questions which show no effort at all.

Comment: Thanks Subash, yes this is what i wanted to know But i resolved it already.

Answer (score 1):

Well the general idea would be to put the `String` values in your `List<String>`. The `add` method is good for that.

Later you should put the key (`1` or `2` according to your example) with the `List<String>` in your map. The `put` method is good for that.

It expects a key (your integer number) and a value (your list of strings).

Answer (score 0):

If you need some direction here is a link with all you need to know about HashMap.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html